# Cite bibliography through the document

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

I am having some trouble in citing articles from my bibliography in the lateX document.
I have created a section as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document} text \cite{1} more text. 

   \begin{thebibliography}{20}
    
    \bibitem{1} bla bla bla
    
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The output is

```
[1] bla bla bla
```

When I refer to this in my document, I call it by \cite{1}. However, instead of [1], I get its number as footnote.

Can you please tell me hot to get [1] instead of its footnote?
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  With the information you provided so far, I can not reproduce the output you describe. (I assume "number as footnote"  stands for a superscript number?) With the following small MWE `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text \cite{1} more text.
\begin{thebibliography}{20}
\bibitem{1} bla bla bla
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}` I end up with this output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBnJv.png

Comment: Therefore, please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Just a guess: Do you load either `\usepackage[super]{natbib}` or `\usepackage[superscript]{cite}` in your preamble? Either of them would cause the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngJw4.png

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. I can provide all the packages I am using, if it can help. I am using `\document class{article}` and `\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}` . Right now, the number of the citation looks like a footnote. Maybe it is due to the package that I am currently using...

Comment: The culprit clearly is the `super` option you added. The `natbib` documentation explicitly states: "`super`: for superscripted numerical citations". Replace `super` with `numbers` and you should get the expected output.

Comment: Thanks a million, leandriis. Yeah, now it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `super` option of `natbib` results in "superscripted numerical citations"  which is exactly what you get from your MWE.

To get non-superscript numerical citations that are surrounded by a set of `[]`, replace the `super` option with `numbers`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[numbers,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document} text \cite{1} more text. 

   \begin{thebibliography}{20}
    
    \bibitem{1} bla bla bla
    
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```